# Separation and integration of variables

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I found $\dfrac{dQ}{dt} = 0.75r - \dfrac{Q(10+r)}{10t+2}$ but I'm having trouble separating my values and integrating to find $Q(t).$

Thank you.

Comment: Please show your work.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to separate out. This is first-order linear, so you can use the integrating factor technique:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dQ}{dt}+\frac{r+10}{10t+2}\,Q&=\frac{3r}{4}.
\end{align*}
The integrating factor is
\begin{align*}
\exp\left(\int \frac{r+10}{10t+2}\,dt\right)&=\exp\left(\frac{1}{10} (r+10) \log (10 t+2)\right)\\
&=(10 t+2)^{\frac{r}{10}+1}.
\end{align*}
It follows that we can write our DE as
\begin{align*}
\frac{dQ}{dt}\,(10 t+2)^{\frac{r}{10}+1}+\frac{r+10}{10t+2}\,Q\,(10 t+2)^{\frac{r}{10}+1}&=\frac{3r}{4}\,(10 t+2)^{\frac{r}{10}+1}\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left[Q(10 t+2)^{\frac{r}{10}+1}\right]&=\frac{3r}{4}\,(10 t+2)^{\frac{r}{10}+1}\\
Q(10 t+2)^{\frac{r}{10}+1}&=\frac{3r}{4}\,\int(10 t+2)^{\frac{r}{10}+1}\,dt\\
&=\frac{3r (5 t+1)^2 (10 t+2)^{r/10}}{r+20}+C\\
Q&=\frac{3r (5 t+1)^2 (10 t+2)^{r/10-r/10-1}}{r+20}+C(10 t+2)^{-\frac{r}{10}-1}\\
&=\frac{3r (5 t+1)^2 }{(r+20)(10 t+2)}+C(10 t+2)^{-\frac{r}{10}-1}\\
&=\frac{3r (10 t+2) }{4(r+20)}+C(10 t+2)^{-\frac{r}{10}-1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: When I use this equation it does not give me the correct answer. I have to find t knowing that Q = 0.95, r = 20 and C= 6. The answer it gives me is not correct. I obtained 0.1081, do you get something different? @AdrianKeister

Comment: Is your $C$ the same as my $C?$ It's a bit odd to be solving for $t$, when it's more usual to think of $Q$ as the dependent variable.

Comment: The problem is as following: Assume the mixing chamber contains 2 liters of clear liquid at time =0
How many minutes will it take for the outflow concentration to rise to within 5% of the desired concentration of 0.5 kilograms per liter? Where Q is the amount of salt in the tank at any given t and r = 20. I also found  C=6 with the initial condition. Is this wrong or right? @AdrianKeister

Comment: You should have included all that detail in your original question, so we could check if you've formulated the DE correctly. If you do that now, you might even be able to get the question re-opened.